# How do I stop a python file by using a script

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python and need to stop my code at some point. is there a way I can use a command to outright just stop my code. for example if have a bunch of while loops running instead of making all the conditions false so the program stops I want to just outright force stop it.

Comment: Yes, ctrl + c. What is the issue?

Comment: [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit)

Comment: I'm gonna fill in some blanks and assume you use `except` without a specific  exception. In that case, you're the architect of your own issues. _at a minimum_ you should use `except Exception`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

or use:

```
raise SystemExit
```

or:

```
exit()
```

or press Ctrl+C to interrupt the execution